# $(...).html(...) rendering inner HTML as text in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a piece of code

```
                // separate pargraph words by spans
                $layer.find('p').each(function(){
                    var words = $(this).html().split(" ");
                    for ( var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i )
                    {
                        words[i] = '<span class="word">' + words[i] + '</span>';
                    }
                    $(this).html(words.join(" "));
                });
                // add event click event on headlines 
                $layer.find('h3').click(function () {
                    $(this).closest('.tower-layer').find('span.word').removeClass('shown');
                    var $wspans = $(this).closest('.tower-layer').find('span.word');
                    for ( var i = 0; i < $wspans.length; ++i )
                    {
                        (function(j){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $($wspans[j]).addClass('shown');
                            },j*100);
                        })(i);
                    }
                });
```

which, as you see, separates HTML into words wrapped in spans and shows them on certain events. The problem I'm having is that in ***FireFox*** the `span`s come out as text rather than DOM elements. Any idea how to fix this? Or is there some other underlying code smell?

Comment: If you want to make a jsbin/jsfiddle of this I'd be happy to take a look

Comment: @elzi There you go: https://jsfiddle.net/ra91Lxcm/ I copied the code above, and it's working fine in all browsers (just changed the timeout).

Comment: Can confirm that @blex code works in Firefox 45.0.1 for me as well.